# Video Player Options for Android

Tags: android

Android has a built in VideoPlayer which would seem to be the goto option, but just wondering if there might be even better open source video players for Android? This is for playing video within a commercial non-rooted android tablet.

Comment: Anything else beside dolphin-player?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/

Comment: Does it have some advantages over the built in player?

Comment: @Code Droid It's open source so one can study the code. There are many non-opensource players definitely superior though